# How to crawl obfuscated web page contents using python requests ,BeautifulSoup and/or scrapy or selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was able to crawl twitter content using GET parameter and parse the data in BeautifulSoup but now all of the website seems obfuscated for HTML elements.

https://www.twitter.com/search?q=donald%20trump&src=typed_query&f=user

this is what I was using to fetch joining date of multiple users named "Donald Trump"

## python and beautifulsoup

```
op_date_time=soup.find_all(class_='ProfileHeaderCard-joinDateText js-tooltip u-dir')
print(op_date_time)
```

This is how the obfuscated code looks now:

```html
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1re7ezh r-4qtqp9 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-zso239 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="r-1re7ezh r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-7o8qx1 r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr"><g><path d="M19.708 2H4.292C3.028 2 2 3.028 2 4.292v15.416C2 20.972 3.028 22 4.292 22h15.416C20.972 22 22 20.972 22 19.708V4.292C22 3.028 20.972 2 19.708 2zm.792 17.708c0 .437-.355.792-.792.792H4.292c-.437 0-.792-.355-.792-.792V6.418c0-.437.354-.79.79-.792h15.42c.436 0 .79.355.79.79V19.71z"></path><circle cx="7.032" cy="8.75" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="7.032" cy="13.156" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="16.968" cy="8.75" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="16.968" cy="13.156" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="8.75" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="13.156" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="7.032" cy="17.486" r="1.285"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="17.486" r="1.285"></circle></g></svg>Joined March 2009</span>
```

Comment: In the python code I was able to fetch and parse data due to defined HTML controls,but now it is not possible to do so as the controls have been obfuscated.Is there any way in which i can parse the obfuscated website?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it was obfuscated code, just html code without id.

You can use built-in [css selector on BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Example for you test on Doda Tram twitter should be:

```
joindt = soup.select('span.r-1re7ezh:nth-child(3)')
```

Edit 1:
twitter seems to use javascript render, wich python requests library cannot handle, so if you use selenium or other like this for javascript you should search for css selector function on it.